# VB.NET Remove First line

Tags: vb.net

This is my code i tried but it removes 2 lines not one

```
    Dim b As String() = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbNewLine)
    TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, b, 1, b.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`b.Length - 1` cause the last element to be removed while joining.

To remove the first line, the start index should be `2`.

Try: `TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, b, 2, b.Length)`

Comment: Yes... I want the first line to be removed

Comment: That did nothing.. My code removes 2 lines but i only want it to remove the top line

Comment: Did you try with 2 as start index ?

Comment: ACtually im using it in a timer and the timer is making it go 2 down

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in another part of your program, see this shot of the debugger:
[image]

maybe you call the routine twice? with timers, take care